# SFML undefined reference to `Bat::Bat(float, float)'

Tags: c++, undefined, sfml

I've been trying to teach myself SFML. Recently I've been following this tutorial: http://gamecodeschool.com/sfml/building-a-simple-game-engine-in-c-plus-plus/ to build a little pong game. The first attempt I read through everything and followed along with the code, and kept getting errors for Bat and Ball, such as:

```
main.cxx:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `Bat::Bat(float, float)'
```

I went back through and tried fixing things, comparing code side by side, and even rewriting each file. However, I still keep getting the same errors:

```
main.cxx:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `Bat::Bat(float, float)'
main.cxx:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `Bat::Bat(float, float)'
main.cxx:(.text+0x279): undefined reference to `Bat::moveLeft()'
```

etc.

I understand that an undefined reference means that the linker can't find the definitions when looking through all of the object files and libraries. However, I haven't worked with C++ in a while, and I honestly can't seem to find where I am going wrong?

My current environment is Geany IDE on Debian 9. All of the header and implementation files are in the same folder. The code is exactly as it is in the tutorial in the link posted above. For example, here is my Bat.h file:

```
ifndef BAT_H
#define BAT_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;

class Bat
{
private:
    Vector2f position;

    // A RectangleShape object
    RectangleShape batShape;

    float batSpeed = .3f;

public:
    Bat(float startX, float startY);

    FloatRect getPosition();

    RectangleShape getShape();

    void moveLeft();

    void moveRight();

    void update();

};
#endif
```

Can someone point me in the right direction or possibly tell me what I am doing wrong? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, we can see the declarations. What about the definitions ? Did you also compile the corresponding cpp file (Bat.cxx I presume ?) and link it when you made your executable ? Maybe the cpp file wasn't correctly added to the project (or whatever name your IDE use to refer to the collection of source files used to build your executable) ? It's a bit hard to tell with these informations. (btw, you're missing a # on the first line, but I assume it's there in the original file, otherwise you'd certainly have a pretty explicit error)

Comment: I've compiled all of the corresponding cpp files, no problem. It's only when I try to build do I get that error I am referring to.

Comment: Have you tried to write your own Makefile to be sure you're not forgetting something (instead of using your IDE)? Granted, it's more tedious, but at least it's easier to see where the problem happens. Alternatively, does typing "g++ [all your cpp files] -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-windows -L[path to where your sfml libraries are located] -I[path to where your sfml headers are located]" in a terminal works ?
I think it has more to do with the building process rather than what's in the source files, but it's really hard to tell without knowing exactly what you have and what you did.

Comment: Your build appears to be missing `Bat.o`.

Answer (score 0):

The linker cannot find the code for you `Bat` constructor and `moveLeft` methods. Most likely cause is that you have either not included your Bat.cpp file in the build, or your cpp file has a different signature for those methods, that differs from the one in your header file.

If you check it and still cannot find the cause, post your cpp file here, too.